# Plot SuperWasp Lightcurves

Tags: amateur-observing, exoplanet, python, light-curve

I am trying to plot superwasp lightcurves in python from the fits files, using TMID and FLUX2, getting this:

[image]

There is a way to transform the information so I can plot the lightcurves with the kepler format, a example from kepler is something like this:

[image]

Any help is useful.

Comment: What is your question? What is on the axes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are expecting to see from the two datasets. Both datasets are examples of light curves, flux against time with different arbitrary origins for the time axis; SuperWASP `TMID` is integer seconds from Julian Date 2453005.5, Kepler uses BKJD = Barycentric Kepler Julian Date, but offset by 2454833.0. i.e., BKJD = BJD - 2454833.0. The SuperWASP datasets typically span 4 years (it's a little difficult to read the plot scales of the example) and are from a ground-based set of small (11.1 cm diameter) lenses with a CCD and so will have day gaps and weather. Kepler/K2 data are from a space-based 95cm telescope which was able to stare at the same patch of sky continuously for about 90 days before a break (and of course had no weather). Consequently there will be a considerable difference in appearance and photometric precision of the lightcurves.

[This page](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/API_superwasptimeseries_columns.html) at the NASA Exoplanet Archive gives details on the SuperWASP public data and [this Python Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/spacetelescope/notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/MAST/K2/K2_Lightcurve/k2_lightcurve.ipynb) has info on plotting K2 light curves.

(Disclaimer: I worked on the SuperWASP project for several years)

Comment: I thought that superwasp used some type of transformation and that for this reason there was no light curve like Kepler. Now I understand the plots better, thank you very much !!